# JProfiler 7.2.2 IDE integration error with Eclipse 4.2

Tags: eclipse, integration, jprofiler

I've JProfiler 7.2.2 installed (with Evaluation Key however), I'm using eclipse 4.2. When I try to integrate JProfiler to Eclipse, it shows the following error message:

The directory C:\Program Files\eclipse\dropins\com.jprofiler.integrations.eclipse could not be created.

What is the issue? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Please do not put an Eclipse installation into the program files folder. Historically Eclipse has been designed for in-place self-modification, but the "Program Files" folder is not writable for normal users. Use a folder instead, which can be written to by any user, e.g. something like c:\eclipse.

Side note: Most eclipse functionality works fine even in a non writable directory, as Eclipse will store the configuration information at a different location then. But not all plugins have been designed and crafted with this in mind.